# How do I need to query (Xpath) for table do not have ID

Tags: python

for example, I have

```
{table 1}
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

{table 2}
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

{table 3}
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I query the table below `{table 3}`? Since the tables don't have an ID, is it possible to write it like this?

```
x.xpath("//table")[2]
```

Comment: which library do you use for the query?

Comment: Are you scraping with bs4?

Comment: It would be helpful to have the complete html: than we can probably come up with a traversal.